# What is the correct syntax to test whether a structure key and data exists?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I am having an issue testing for the existence of a specific structure key and data using structKeyExists().

I want my query results to be stored in structures like this:

```
APPLICATION.MemQs.ProdCountQs[1].ExpirationDate;
APPLICATION.MemQs.ProdCountQs[1].ProdCount;
APPLICATION.MemQs.ProdCountQs[2].ExpirationDate;
APPLICATION.MemQs.ProdCountQs[2].ProdCount;
APPLICATION.MemQs.ProdCountQs[3].ExpirationDate;
APPLICATION.MemQs.ProdCountQs[3].ProdCount;

// CREATE MEMORY QUERIES ~ works great
if (structKeyExists(APPLICATION, "MemQs") == false) {
    APPLICATION.MemQs = structNew();
}

// CREATE PRODUCT COUNT QUERIES ~ works great
if (structKeyExists(APPLICATION.MemQs, "ProdCountQs") == false) {
    APPLICATION.MemQs.ProdCountQs= structNew();
}

// fails the test ~ always recreates variables
if (structKeyExists(APPLICATION.MemQs, "ProdCountQs[SomeID]") == false) {
    APPLICATION.MemQs.ProdCountQs[SomeID] = structNew();
    APPLICATION.MemQs.ProdCountQs[SomeID].ExpirationDate = now();
    APPLICATION.MemQs.ProdCountQs[SomeID].ProdCount = 0;
}

// fails the test ~ always recreates variables
if (structKeyExists(APPLICATION.MemQs.ProdCountQs, "[SomeID]") == false) {
    APPLICATION.MemQs.ProdCountQs[SomeID] = structNew();
    APPLICATION.MemQs.ProdCountQs[SomeID].ExpirationDate = now();
    APPLICATION.MemQs.ProdCountQs[SomeID].ProdCount = 0;
}

// fails the test ~ always recreates variables
if (structKeyExists(APPLICATION.MemQs.ProdCountQs, "SomeID") == false) {
    APPLICATION.MemQs.ProdCountQs[SomeID] = structNew();
    APPLICATION.MemQs.ProdCountQs[SomeID].ExpirationDate = now();
    APPLICATION.MemQs.ProdCountQs[SomeID].ProdCount = 0;
}

// throws error 
// APPLICATION.MemQs.ProdCountQs[SomeID], must be a syntactically valid variable name
if (isDefined("APPLICATION.MemQs.ProdCountQs[SomeID]") == false) {
    APPLICATION.MemQs.ProdCountQs[SomeID] = structNew();
    APPLICATION.MemQs.ProdCountQs[SomeID].ExpirationDate = now();
    APPLICATION.MemQs.ProdCountQs[SomeID].ProdCount = 0;
}
```

So, how do I use structKeyExists() to test for the existence of

```
APPLICATION.MemQs.ProdCountQs[SomeID]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put pound `##` signs around `SomeID` as it is a variable.

```
if (structKeyExists(APPLICATION.MemQs.ProdCountQs, "#SomeID#") == false) {
   APPLICATION.MemQs.ProdCountQs[SomeID] = structNew();
   APPLICATION.MemQs.ProdCountQs[SomeID].ExpirationDate = now();
   APPLICATION.MemQs.ProdCountQs[SomeID].ProdCount = 0;
}
```

If `SomeID` is not a variable then in that case you should surround `SomeID` in square braces with double quotes `""` like this `APPLICATION.MemQs.ProdCountQs["SomeID"]`. So the code will look like this:

```
if (structKeyExists(APPLICATION.MemQs.ProdCountQs, "SomeID") == false) {
   APPLICATION.MemQs.ProdCountQs["SomeID"] = structNew();
   APPLICATION.MemQs.ProdCountQs["SomeID"].ExpirationDate = now();
   APPLICATION.MemQs.ProdCountQs["SomeID"].ProdCount = 0;
}
```

**EDIT**
As Leigh suggested it is better to use `!` operator instead of checking for `false`. Also if the key is a variable then you can omit the doubles quotes and pound sign while checking for the key. So you can write the `if` condition as follows:

```
if (!structKeyExists(APPLICATION.MemQs.ProdCountQs, SomeID))
```

Comment: *You need to put pound ## signs around SomeID as it is a variable.*  It is worth noting that is only because the variable name is enclosed in quotes, so it is treated as a literal string instead of a variable name.  Omit the quotes and CF will treat `SomeID` as a variable. Also, though using "== false" works, it is shorter to use "!" ie `if ( !structKeyExists(APPLICATION.MemQs.ProdCountQs, SomeID)) {...}`

Comment: I put the pound signs around the variable and it worked perfectly.  Thanks!  structKeyExists(APPLICATION.MemQs.ProdCountQs, "#SomeID#") == false)

Comment: @Leigh. Right. I'm modifying my code to reflect it.

Comment: Pankaj - Cool. That will help the next time the "to quote or not to quote question comes up" ;-) Evik - Yes, though that works I would get rid of both the quotes and the # signs. It is less typing and clearer that `SomeID` is a variable IMO :)

Comment: Also, the proper way to do it is to remove the quotes, instead of adding the pound signs. Since quotes is shorthand for strings, while removing the quotes, you're actually asking CF to check the key against the value of the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to create a structure from a query. You should create the structure first and then populate it from your query. In the sample below I'm assuming you have a query object and that there's columns in that query object called "ExpirationDate" and "ProdCount".

```
// create query structure
if(!structKeyExists(APPLICATION, "MemQs")){
    APPLICATION.MemQs = structNew();
    APPLICATION.MemQs.ProdCountQs = arrayNew();
}
// loop through the query
for(row=1;row<=originalQuery.recordcount;row++){
    APPLICATION.MemQs.ProdCountQs[row] = structNew();
    APPLICATION.MemQs.ProdCountQs[row].ExpirationDate = originalQuery.ExpirationDate[row];
    APPLICATION.MemQs.ProdCountQs[row].ProdCount = originalQuery.ProdCount[row];
}
```

However, if what you want is to check for the existence of the nodes, you should go through the tree incrementally like so:

```
// create query structure
if(!structKeyExists(APPLICATION, "MemQs")){
    APPLICATION.MemQs = structNew();
    if(!structKeyExists(APPLICATION.MemQs, "ProdCountQs")){
        APPLICATION.MemQs.ProdCountQs = arrayNew();
        if(!arrayIsDefined(APPLICATION.MemQs.ProdCountQs,someID)){
            APPLICATION.MemQs.ProdCountQs[someID] = structNew();
            if(!structKeyExists(APPLICATION.MemQs.ProdCountQs[someID], "ExpirationDate")){
                APPLICATION.MemQs.ProdCountQs[someID].ExpirationDate = now();
            }
            if(!structKeyExists(APPLICATION.MemQs.ProdCountQs[someID], "ProdCount")){
                APPLICATION.MemQs.ProdCountQs[someID].ProdCount = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```